# Доступность Яндекс Карт. Встраивание Яндекс Карт

Tags: php, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api, сервисы

Бесплатны ли Яндекс Карты и если да, то как их встроить в код?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/

Comment: бесплатны если в открытом доступе

Answer (score 0):

есть бесплатные версии, но они ограничены по функционалу. встроить можно от сюда https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/